# MS Access Custom Formatting: Currency in K

Tags: ms-access-2013

I am trying to create an appropriate `Format` table property of a specific MS Access table in order to achieve the display style described below. For example purposes, let the table name be `example` and the field that I am trying to format be `dollars`

When `example!dollars.Value` is `567.98`, I wish to display `$0.567K`. I also wish to display `1,000.42` as `$1.000K`.

In another table storing larger values, I use the `Format` property string `$#,##0,\K; ($#,##0,"K)"[Red];"| < $1K |"; --`, which successfully displays the amount in `K` dollars; however, any values less than $1K cannot be displayed. This is not acceptable due to the scale of the values in the `example` table.

The most intuitive solution is to use the string `$0,000\K` and specify the thousands separator as `.` instead of `,`. However, I do not know how to do this.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Kamount = Format(Amount/1000, "$0.000K")
```

So divide by 1000, then format as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Format` property string `$0\.000\K`